# Why do I get nil error when I'm trying to retrieve using Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models such as `User` and `Tracking`

`Tracking` models has these 6 columns below

- id
- user_id
- target_user_id
- accessed_at
- created_at
- updated_at

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many: trackings
```

**models/tracking.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "target_user_id", :class_name => "User"
```

Then in `controllers/trackings_controller.rb`, I coded like this

**controllers**

```
@trackings = Tracking.find_by_target_user_id(current_user.id).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

But I get nil error:( Why is that?
There's no record made yet in trackings table.
How can I retrieve?

if I code it just like this, there's no error ocuured:(

```
@trackings = Tracking.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: As there are no records made yet in trackings table you are getting nil for Tracking.find_by_target_user_id(current_user.id) and then you are doing nil.page(params[:page]). Hence you are getting nil error.

Comment: @Deepika then why don't I get nil error when I'm coding `@trackings = Tracking.page(params[:page]).per(10) ` instead?

Comment: You can see the backtrace of your error and investigate each step very nicely with the [Better errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) gem.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm Thanks. I have already installed it

Comment: @MKK Because find_by_something returns nil if record doesn't exists and Tracking.page(params[:page]).per(10) returning array [] if record doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search trackings for current_user

```
@trackings = Tracking.where(:target_user_id => current_user.id ).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Then what's the poing of Active Record since I cannot use `find_by_something`??

Comment: Look, you need an array of active record in result and find_by_something gives you an active record. That's the case.

Comment: Ahhhh, Active Record only works in the case of one-to-one association?